# How can a PostgreSQL database cease to exist in between two consecutive shell commands?

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql, gitlab-ci, postgres-9.6

I am trying to create a PostgreSQL database `accounts_db` in CI (GitLab CI, if it's relevant), but only if that database does not exist yet. Since native Postgres doesn't support that, I currently solve it by running a `SELECT` on `pg_database` using psql, and only when that does not return results, I use psql again to run a `CREATE DATABASE`:

```
psql -tc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'accounts_db';" | grep -q 1 || psql -c "CREATE DATABASE accounts_db;"
```

This works most of the time: `accounts_db` already exists, so `grep` exits successfully and the `CREATE DATABASE` is not executed.

Most of the time is not all the time, though. For some reason, it sometimes ends up in the second part of the `||`, only to error out because the database already exists:

```
$ psql -tc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'accounts_db';" | grep -q 1 || psql -c "CREATE DATABASE accounts_db;"
ERROR:  database "accounts_db" already exists
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Note:your command does not include a databasename to connect to. Do you have a database with your userid as name?

Comment: Run the first bit without the grep and see what it outputs. Also how doesn't postgres support it, just run the second command...

Comment: Depending on your environment it will output row numbers. As you are searching for the string '1' which is not necessarily the value 1 returned from the select statement. Update your question with the output from the check database select statement for both when it exists for when it doesn't. They will both likely contain a '1' in there.

Comment: `SELECT 'magic_string' from pg_database WHERE ...; | grep -q magic_string ...`

Comment: @wildplasser That's set as an environment variable. Note that it works most of the time.

Comment: @123 Hmm I tried that, but it just outputted `1`. I guess I should try it several times, going to do so now - thanks. The second command works but exits with non-0, leading to a failed CI pipeline. (Although I guess I could override that, but then I'd miss potential other errors.)

Comment: @Mokadillion Hmm, that sounds reasonable. Let me check.

Comment: Personally i would wrap this into a shell script. Save the database list as an array and search through it, if its not present then create a new db. This way you can re-use the script with the db name as in input variable.

Comment: Haha OK, this is getting annoying: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25325734/ (And yes, transforming it into a shell script is a plan for later, when there'll be multiple databases.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW: You don't need grep; you can use psql's exit code,just attempt connecting to the *new* database:
(there are more reasons for psql to exit with non zero exit value; but in that case the second psql will also fail)

```
#!/bin/sh

THE_NAME="omg_wtf"

psql -U postgres ${THE_NAME} -tc "select 'yes';" || psql -U postgres postgres -tc "CREATE DATABASE ${THE_NAME} ;"

#Eof
```

---

But even simpler: just attempt to create the database, and bail out of the script if that fails:

---

```
#!/bin/sh

THE_NAME="omg_wtf"

psql -U postgres postgres -tc "CREATE DATABASE ${THE_NAME} ;"|| exit 1

# you wont get here if the above exited
echo "Created ${THE_NAME}"

#Eof
```

Comment: I actually want it to succeed if the database already exists, but not if there are other errors when creating the database. But your first option sounds good, let met try.

Comment: You can catch the result code `result=$?` in the shell script and act on its value.

Comment: Allright, this appears to work for now. It's a shame that I don't know what the actual problem was, but I'll keep an eye on this and accept this answer if it appears it's no longer failing. In any case thanks for the help :)

Comment: After seven retries, and all seven successful, it appears to be stable enough now. I guess it was something to do with grep, the pipe, or something else Bash-related that I don't have enough experience with Bash for to figure out. Anyway, it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you've obfuscated the real db name, and the real one sometimes contains mixed case?

Because

```
SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'MyDB'
```

will match a database named `MyDB` but not one named `mydb`. However, if you *create* the database, you'll get a case-folded name; e.g.

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDB;
```

creates a db named `mydb`. So in this case, your test for existence would report that there's no db named `MyDB` then you'd go to create it, try to create `mydb` and fail if it already existed.

The fix is to use identifier quoting:

```
CREATE DATABASE "MyDB";
```

to preserve case there. Or alternately, case-fold your query of pg_database to lower case:

```
SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = lower('MyDB')
```

... assuming you know you'll only ever attempt to then create it in lower-case.

(It gets even more exciting if the user decides to supply identifier-quoted input to your script...)

Comment: @Vincent Race condition with multiple concurrent scripts trying to do the same thing then maybe?

Comment: I could see just one CI job executing, and it just ran the command I posted in my question. It also no longer seems to occur after removing grep...